# How can I redirect the user to login or different page if the user hasn't signed in using OAuth 2.0

Tags: oauth

So I'm fairly new to OAuth 2.0 and I'm trying to figure out how I can check if the user hasn't logged in using OAuth 2.0 and it will be redirected to the login page so that any page the user will visit needs to login first. Have been searching for answers but so far I haven't seen any answer

```
function init() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function() {
        // init auth2 with your hosted_domain
        // only matching accounts will show up in the list or be accepted

        var auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
            client_id: "962756035262-56p0avnoc8cm8ahmhjs9krc4mktt47uq.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            hosted_domain: 'frostdesigngroup.com'
        });
    });

}

init();
```

Answer (score 0):

OAuth 2.0 is not about the user.

OAuth 2.0 is about your application being Authorized to access a resource.

The method that you obtain that Authorization is to submit an "Authorization Request" to the "Authorization Server" to obtain an "Access Token".

You will not know how (or technically if) the user has "logged in" or not.

So if your application does not have an "Access Token", it is up to your application to determine the appropriate "Authorization Server" to send the "Authorization Request".

It is a "Best Practice" for you utilize a known good OAuth Library for these activities.